# How to loop through an array of objects passed to a component with Vuex Store & a computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components, vuex

I'm building a project to learn **[Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)**. I'm creating an array of objects in my **`store`** like so:

**Vuex Store:**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users: [
      { id: 1, name: 'John Doe', email: 'johndoe@gmail.com' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', email: 'janedoe@gmail.com'  },
      { id: 3, name: 'Mark Greywood', email: 'markgreywood@gmail.com'  },
    ]
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {}
});
```

Now, I'm accesing the **`state`** in the component with a computed property like so:

**Component:**

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <h1>Hello from Home component</h1>

   <!-- I do not loop through the users, nothing shows --> 
    <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">{{ user.name }} </div>

   <!-- I get the users object in the DOM -->
    <div>{{ getUsers }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: "Index",
  computed: mapState({
    getUsers: state => state.users
  })
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="less">

</style>
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have access to `users` in this line of code

`<div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">{{ user.name }} </div>`

Your component only have access to `getUsers` (the computed property) which is mapped to the store object `users`. Thus whenever the `users` state on your store changes, `getUser` also gets updated. So you should iterate on the computed property in your component.

So, the iteration should be

`<div v-for="user in getUsers" :key="user.id">{{ user.name }} </div>`

Comment: Thank you so much saved me hours of pain I didn't know what was wrong. Still a beginner tho'

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
    <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">{{ user.name }} </div>
```

To this

```
    <div v-for="user in getUsers" :key="user.id">{{ user.name }} </div>
```

With your mapState line you are kinda telling component - 'Hey my store.users are in the getUsers variable'
Component do not know about 'users'. You didn't create variable like that.

Another way is to change loop to

```
    <div v-for="user in $store.state.users" :key="user.id">{{ user.name }} </div>
```

In that case you can delete computed property 'getUsers'